# Query separate collection in RavenDB Index (WHERE IN)

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

Using RavenDB v4.2 or higher, I want to setup an index that queries another collection. Basically, reproduce a WHERE IN clause in the mapping part of the index.

The models below represent two collections. Here each `User` has a collection of Device ID's:

```cs
class Device {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class User {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public List<string> DeviceIds { get; set; } 
}
```

Now consider the following index as an example on what I'm trying to achieve:

```cs
public class DeviceIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Device, DeviceIndex.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public bool HasUser { get; set; }
        public int UserCount { get; set; }
    }
    public DeviceIndex()
    {
        Map = devices => from d in devices
                         select new Result
                         {
                             Id = d.Id,
                             DeviceName = d.Name,

                             HasUser = ... ?, // How to get this from Users collection?
                             UserCount = ... ? // same...

                         };

    }
```

How do I fill the `HasUser` true/false and `UserCount` properties in this index? E.g. how can I query the 'User' collection here?

Please note that this example is seriously simplified for brevity. I'm not so much interested in workarounds, or changing the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Danielle mentioned you need to use a mutli-map-index and reduce the result.
Here is a working example

```
public class DeviceIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<DeviceIndex.Result>
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string DeviceName { get; set; }
            public bool HasUser { get; set; }
            public int UserCount { get; set; }
        }
        public DeviceIndex()
        {
            AddMap<User>(users => from u in users
                                  from deviceId in u.DeviceIds
                                  let d = LoadDocument<Device>(deviceId)
                                select new Result
                                {
                                    Id = d.Id,
                                    HasUser = true,
                                    UserCount = 1,
                                    DeviceName = d.Name,
                                });
            AddMap<Device>(devices => from d in devices
                                      select new Result
                                      {
                                          Id = d.Id,
                                          HasUser = false,
                                          UserCount = 0,
                                          DeviceName = d.Name,
                                      });

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by new { result.Id } into g
                                select new Result
                                {
                                    Id = g.First().Id,
                                    DeviceName = g.First().DeviceName,
                                    HasUser = g.Any(e => e.HasUser),
                                    UserCount = g.Sum(e => e.UserCount),
                                };

        }
    }
```

and you can call it like this

```
var result = await _session.Query<DeviceIndex.Result, DeviceIndex>().ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have a Users List in the *Device* class 
`List<string> Users`
a list that contains the document ids from the *Users* collection then you could **Index these Related documents.**

See:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/index-related-documents

Or do the opposite, 
Create an index on the *Users* collection, and index the related *Device* info

---

Without changing current models, 
You can create a **Multi-Map Index** to index data from different collections.

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/indexes/multi-map-indexes

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/studio/database/indexes/create-multi-map-index

https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/10-static-indexes-and-other-advanced-options#querying-many-sources-at-once-with-multimap-indexes

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the answer, but this is exactly what I mean with "...not being interested in workarounds/or changing logic behind it...". I don't want to remodel - but looking to find an answer to this precise question.

Comment: In that case, you can use Multi-Map Index - I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks. But in the referenced docs I see more polymorphism examples e.g. concat same properties. More like a union. Besides a link to the docs, can you provide a short (pseudo/fake) code sample using my example - I simply don't see it?